# How to access same multiprocessing namespace from different modules

Tags: python, module, namespaces, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I need to be able to create shared object with pySerial object in it. This object will be created by child process only once after finding device from list of locations. Other processes will use it in later time.

Python multiprocessing manager can't know about changes to objects embedded to other objects.
So if I create manager:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
manager=mp.Manager()
ns=manager.Namespace()
```

I can share object between processes.

```
ns.obj = SerialReader()
```

where

```
class SerialReader(object):

    port = None
    def connect(self):

        #some code to test connected device 
        ...
        #end of that code

        ser=serial.Serial(device, etc)
        self.ser=ser 
        #or
        self.saveport() #for future use

    def saveport(self):
        self.port = self.ser._port
        ns.port= self.ser._port
```

Now I will run it in child process:

```
p=Process(target = ns.obj.connect)
p.start()
```

and print results:

```
print ns.obj.port
print ns.port
```

Output:

```
None
/dev/ttyACM0
```

I whant to be able to use simple code like:

ns.obj.ser.write(), 
ns.obj.somemethod(arg) where

```
...inside SerialReaders class...
def somemethod(self, arg):
    if arg == condition:
        self.ser.write('some text %s' %arg)
```

but I can't make refference to ns.obj.ser because it will be concidered as not defined if it will be run from new process. The same situation we will get if we will reference self.ser in other methods inside conntrollers.py and try to run them in new process.

EDIT: I found way to import namespace to module:

```
from __main__ import ns
```

or by sending ns to **init** when creating object.
But problem still exist. ns.obj is NoneType object because this object is still in process of creation. So I can't type ns.obj.ser= self.ser
If I try to send ns to SerialReader()

```
ns.obj = SerialReader(ns)
```

and try to print it inside SerialReader_*init*_ I get:

```
<NamespaceProxy object, typeid 'Namespace' at 0xa21b70c; '__str__()' failed>
```

I can't add ser to it too..

Comment: Separate processes have different address spaces, so the variable `ns` can be only used in one process (unless you use shared memory). Have you considered multithreading?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes I am using it in this case. I've corrected a bit question. Maybe it will be easier to understand now.